# Confused on the locations of class declaration and implementation in c++

Tags: c++, class

I have not been able to find the specific answer to this -- I do know that .h files contain class declarations and .cpp files hold the implementation.

I am confused as to how this is done without repetition.

If I have a class Animal it might be called in several areas of the program. So it would seem I would have to re-write the implementation several times (which no doubt means I am misunderstood).

It seems a bit goofy to include a .h declaration and .cpp implentation with every use of the given class (evidence I am misunderstanding something as well).

Where have I gone wrong in the subject of separating declaration and implementation?

I've been doing PHP and Python all of this time, so it might be prior habits confusing me.

Comment: Why do you need to rewrite the implementation? You just `#include` the header where you need the class.

Comment: You need a clear understanding of what #include is for.  [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive) or use the google box...

Comment: This is a tricky aspect of C++ that is often taken for granted by C++ programmers.  There is something in C++ called the **"One Definition Rule"** that, in summary, and a bit simplified, states that for every object file (called a 'translation unit' in the C++ standard) there can be only one declaration of a function/class - and that ACROSS translation units, if the class declaration occurs for the same class, it must be identical.  This allows programmers to write the code for the class declarations once (in the header file), and reuse it across source files.

Comment: Read up on the difference between *compilation* and *linking.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.cpp` files are compiled *once* into object (`.o`) files.
They are *never* included into other `.cpp` files (that would lead to multiple definitions, which are an error in the general case).

Declarations, which are generally retrieved by `#include`ing header files, are how one `.cpp` file can know what's defined in *some* other `.cpp` file and use it without actually having its definition.

Once all of the `.cpp` files have been compiled into object files, the linker comes along and links all the object files together to form the final executable or library.
If multiple definitions of the same thing are found, or if one is missing, that's a linker error.

Comment: So if I have 3 cpp files using class `Animal` from Animal.h, I need only write the implementation in 1 cpp file, and it will be recognized by the 2 others?

Comment: @Pipsqweek yes. `Animal.cpp` would contain `Animal`'s implementation. The three other `.cpp` files would learn via `Animal.h` that `Animal` is a class with such and such functions, members, etc. Then it's the linker job to tie it all together, by noticing that `Foo.o` wants to call `Animal::eat()`, which is defined in `Animal.o`.

Comment: I get it now thank you so much. There is a little voice in my mind saying "damn my `import modulename` eyes!"

Comment: @Pipsqweek my pleasure! The header inclusion system is one of C++'s weaknesses according to a lot of people, but it does work fine if you document yourself before using it. There's also an ongoing effort to standardize a system for "true" modules, which we might see in C++20 :)